# cant get color animation to work

Tags: jquery

Simple just trying to animate a p-tag #disclaimer to highlight the background color.

Example in jQuery:

```
$('#disclaimer').animate({'backgroundColor':'#ff9f5f'}, 2000);
```

The html is a simple

```
<p id="disclaimer"> disclaimer here </p>
```

But when I try to open the page in IE here is the JS error:

Webpage error details

> User Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;
>   MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/4.0;
>   SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR
>   3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C;
>   .NET4.0E; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)
>   Timestamp: Mon, 26 Jul 2010 17:57:09
>   UTC
>
> Message: Invalid property value. Line:
>   141 Char: 6 Code: 0 URI:
>   file:///C:/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/MyJQuerySite/lib/jquery-1.4.min.js

Am I doing something incorrectly ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jQuery doesn't natively support animations on colors. In order for this to work you'll need to include the [jQuery color](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/color) plugin.

Here's a blurb about it in the [jQuery 1.2 Release Notes](http://docs.jquery.com/Release:jQuery_1.2/Effects#Color_Animations).